# Gedit in Windows creates multiple instances

Tags: windows, tabs, multiple-instances, gedit

I installed the latest version (*2.30.1*) of **Gedit** for Windows. And whenever I open files from explorer with gedit, it won't open as tabs in the current instance, instead it opens a new window for each file, like a notepad. I do not like this behavior. Is there any way to configure gedit to open files in the same window as tabs?

Comment: This question covers platform specific issue whilst using "software tools commonly used by programmers". Not being able to open multiple files from a single project in a single instance of the application is a problem for me too. plus I invested a bounty into getting an answer which hasn't been posted yet :(

Answer (score 1):

Judging from [this askubuntu.org post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti), this is not only an issue on windows. Making the suggested changes and building gedit for windows might yield some result.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the best answer, but you can try Notepad++ instead of Gedit for Windows. It has basically the same features (and I actually find Notepad++ better - a friend of mine uses Wine with Notepad++ on Ubuntu).
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/